# How to transfer data from fragment to fragment in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, pager

I have two fragment.

Fragment 1 has a radio button

Fragment 2 Has a textview

So, What should I do to display "radio button from fragment 1 was chosen" on text view of fragment 2??

I tried a lot of ways but it does not work :(

My code:
Fragment 1:

```
    public class fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container,false);
    }

}
```

Fragment 2:

```
public class fragment2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container,false);
    }

}
```

Main_Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    ViewPager pager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fm));
    }
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
            CharSequence title = null;
            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                title ="Tab 1";
                break;
            case 1:
                title ="Tab 2";
                break;

            return title;
        }
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                fragment = new fragment1();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new fragment2();
                break;

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 2;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

THanks for your Help!!!!!!